# C#, Why passing an int[] to a HashSet<T> adds a default element of value zero

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner in C# so I hope to get your help here. I just wanted to know why passing an array with a specific size adds a default element of value 0 to the HashSet.
Example:

```
int[] arr = new int[4]; 
HshSet<int> myHashSet = new HashSet<int>(arr);
myHashSet.Count(); //The count is equal to 1 and the first element's value is zero.
```

Can you please explain to me why this happens? Is this behavior unique for HashSets only or does it also apply to the other generic collections?

Comment: [Use your debugger](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/) to look at the contents of `arr`. If you don't understand how `HashSets` work [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_Generic_HashSet_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`arr` is initialized as an array of four zeros, since that's the default value for an int.  You haven't actually given the array any specific values just initialized it with a length.

HashSets can not contain duplicate values so when you give it four zeros via its constructor the last three are discarded.